# A need of high frequency ranges from 6MHz to 27MHz

Tags: operational-amplifier

I need to generate a high frequency square waveform that ranges from 6MHz to 27Mhz (preferably 10MHz) to act as a Master clock for my MT9P031 image sensor. What circuit should I use to generate such waveform with the involvement of an OpAmp.

Comment: Why do you want to use an op-amp?  How accurate and stable do you need the frequency to be?   Can you run an LC or varactor-tuned VFO open loop, or do you need something PLL locked to a reference?  Are your needed frequency steps course enough that you can divide them down from some higher reference?

Comment: Do you need a fixed output frequency, which can be anywhere between 6 and 27 MHz; or do you need a circuit that allows you to adjust the frequency from time to time?

Comment: I'm sure the manufacturer of the MT9P031 has recommendations on design. have you looked at those? They should be the best fit.

Answer (score 3):

You need a [crystal oscillator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_oscillator). These are available in a [range of different frequencies](http://uk.farnell.com/oscillators-standard). You simply apply power, and out comes the frequency you want.

[image: Crystal Oscillator]